# Set fixed part size in Eclipse E4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have an application that I am building in in e4 but am having trouble getting a couple parts to be a fixed size. I have a `PartSashContainer` with two `Parts` and another `PartSashContainer` in it. I initially set size in the `containerData` parameter, but these values are relative and still allow for re-sizing of the parts. I want to make sure these parts are a fixed height and can not be re-sized. Is there an easy way of doing this?

[image: List view from Application.e4xmi]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse bug [361731](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361731) is a request for this feature. Currently it has not been implemented.

It might be possible to do with a custom renderer, but this is hard work.

Comment: That is kind of what I figured. I saw that bug report a while ago, but didn't know if someone had another solution in the mean time, other than a custom renderer. Do you know of any good examples of a custom renderer?

Comment: No I haven't seen any example renderers.

Comment: darn, well that is unfortunate. This seems like a such a simple feature, and apparently it was in older versions of e4, but is no longer for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this was available before Neon, but Eclipse Neon allows you to add "NoMove" as a Tag to the `Part Sash Container` that you would like to lock down and not resize.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar task and stumbled across your question several times. I need to implement a RCP application, following a Corporate Design with a fixed size application header and a fixed size footer. I found no perfect way, but the [vogella tutorial on custom renderers](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) gave me some hints. I still had to duplicate some code, I didn't find a clever way around.

My requirements:

- Application Header on top with fixed height, no controls above the
  header
- Application Header on top with fixed size, no controls above the header
- Application Footer at the bottom, again with a fixed height

**So what I did was:**

- Remove everything that is rendered above the first part (Main Menu,
  Tool Bars...)
- Create the Part Sash Container with 1 Part (header), 2 whatever Control you need (content), 3 last Part (footer)
- In this Part Sash Container do the following:

  1. add "fx_fixedLayout" to "Tags" (as I don't want re-sizing the Sash)
  2. add "CUSTOM_RENDERER_UI=my.renderer.MainSashRenderer" to "Persisted
     State"
- create a copy of
  "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashLayout" and name it
  "my.renderer.MainSashLayout". Change method "tileSubNodes" and set
  fixed height for the first and last child.
- Extend class "SashRenderer" and call it "MainSashRenderer"
- Create a new "MainWorkbenchRendererFactory" extending
  "WorkbenchRendererFactory", to hook your new renderer in. This class
  only attaches the "MainSashRenderer" to "MPartSashContainer" objects
  with a specific ID (because I want all other Sashes to be untouched).

---

```
public class MainWorkbenchRendererFactory extends WorkbenchRendererFactory {

    private final static String MAIN_SASH_ID = "myapp.partsashcontainer.main";

    @Override
    public AbstractPartRenderer getRenderer(MUIElement uiElement, Object parent) {
        if (uiElement instanceof MPartSashContainer
        && MAIN_SASH_ID.equalsIgnoreCase(((MPartSashContainer)uiElement).getElementId())) {
            MainSashRenderer renderer = new MainSashRenderer();
            super.initRenderer(renderer);
            return renderer;
        }
        return super.getRenderer(uiElement, parent);
    }
}
```

In class "MainSashRenderer", change reference from "SashLayout" to "MainSashLayout".

In class "MainSashLayout", method tileSubNodes:

```
    // subsctract size for header and footer:
    availableSpace -= (this.footerHeightPx + this.headerHeightPx);

    // Subtract off the room for the sashes
    availableSpace -= ((childCount - 1) * sashWidth);

    if (availableSpace < 0)
    availableSpace = 0;

    for (MUIElement subNode : visibleChildren) {

    if (childNum == 0) {
        newSize = this.headerHeightPx;
    } else if (childNum == visibleChildren.size()-1) {
        newSize = this.footerHeightPx;
    } else {
        // Calc the new size as a %'age of the total
        double ratio = getWeight(subNode) / totalWeight;
        newSize = (int) ((availableSpace * ratio) + 0.5);
    }
...
```

Result with different window sizes (header and footer keep their pixel height):
[Screenshots with different window sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4J67.png)